# Numpy, matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

It is a simple question, when making predictions, is there any advantage to doing `W @ X.T` over `X @ W`or 
Is it just a waste of resources to make the transpose to predict values?

For example:

```
print(W)
# array([18.56711151,  4.51542094])

print(X)
# [[1.    6.575]
#  [1.    6.421]
#  [1.    7.185]
#  ...
#  [1.    6.976]
#  [1.    6.794]
#  [1.    6.03 ]]

yP = W @ X.T
yP_ X @ W 
yP == yP_
#True
```

Comment: no, transpose is cheap

Comment: so what's the advantage of doing `W @ X.T`respect to `X @ W`?

Comment: is it always true that `W @ X.T == X @ W` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [57]: W = np.array([1,2])                                                             
In [58]: X = np.ones((4,2))                                                              
In [59]: X[:,1] = [1,2,3,4]                                                              
In [60]: W                                                                               
Out[60]: array([1, 2])
In [61]: X                                                                               
Out[61]: 
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 2.],
       [1., 3.],
       [1., 4.]])
In [62]: X.T                                                                             
Out[62]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 2., 3., 4.]])
In [63]: W@X.T                                                                           
Out[63]: array([3., 5., 7., 9.])
In [64]: X@W                                                                             
Out[64]: array([3., 5., 7., 9.])
```

The first `@` uses (4,) and (2,4) shape to produce a (4,).

The second uses a (4,2) and (4,).

Look at `matmul` for rules on how it handles 1d arguments such as your `W`.

I find the `einsum` notation helps clarify which axes are combined:

```
In [75]: np.einsum('i,ji->j', W,X)                                                       
Out[75]: array([3., 5., 7., 9.])
```

The effect of switch arguments in `@` might be clearer if `W` was 2d.

```
In [76]: W1                 # (2,1) shape                                                             
Out[76]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])
In [77]: W1.T@X.T           # (1,2) with (2,4) produces (1,4)                                                                       
Out[77]: array([[3., 5., 7., 9.]])
In [78]: _.shape                                                                         
Out[78]: (1, 4)
```

(4,2) with (2,1) produces (4,1)

```
In [79]: X@W1                                                                            
Out[79]: 
array([[3.],
       [5.],
       [7.],
       [9.]])
In [80]: _.shape                                                                         
Out[80]: (4, 1)
```

[77] and [80] can be transposed to each other, e.g `((W1.T)@(X.T)).T` to produce (4,1).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks a lot, it was clear and simple! :)